# Endless 500 error, php sendgrid api

Tags: php

I'm running in to an issue getting PHP to connect to SendGrid (using their library) and send a message.  Whenever I click the submit button on the form to send me a message, it runs through jQuery like so:

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var c_name = $("#c_name").val();
            var c_email = $("#c_email").val();
            var c_message = $("#c_message ").val();
            var responseMessage = $('.ajax-response');


            if (( c_name== "" || c_email == "" || c_message == "") || (!isValidEmailAddress(c_email) )) {
                responseMessage.fadeIn(500);
                responseMessage.html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Check all fields.');
            }

            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "assets/php/sendgrid-php/contactForm.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        c_email: c_email,
                        c_name: c_name,
                        c_message: c_message
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(result) {
                        $('#contact-form button').empty();
                        $('#contact-form button').append('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Wait...');
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result.sendstatus == 1) {
                            console.log(result);
                            responseMessage.html(result.message);
                            responseMessage.fadeIn(500);
                            $('#contact-form').fadeOut(500);
                        } else {
                            console.log(result);
                            console.log(c_name + " " + c_email + " " + c_message);
                            $('#contact-form button').empty();
                            $('#contact-form button').append('<i class="fa fa-retweet"></i> Please try again.');
                            responseMessage.html(result.message);
                            responseMessage.fadeIn(1000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

When it posts to the URL, it runs to the contactForm.php file which has the following:

```
<?php
require 'sendgrid-php.php';

  $sendgrid = new SendGrid('(my user)', '(my pass)', $options = array(
    'turn_off_ssl_verification' => false,
    'protocol' => 'https',
    'host' => 'api.sendgrid.com',
    'endpoint' => '/api/mail.send.json',
    'port' => null,
    'url' => null,
  ));
  $email = new Sendgrid\Email();

try {
  $email ->addTo('(my email)@outlook.com')
         ->setFrom($_POST['c_email'])
         ->setSubject("From Portfolio")
         ->setText($_POST['c_message']);

  $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
  if (!$response) {
        throw new Exception("Did not receive response.");
    } else if ($response->message && $response->message == "error") {
        throw new Exception("Received error: ".join(", ", $response->errors));
    } else {
        $result = array(
                'message' => 'Thanks for contacting us!',
                'sendstatus' => 1
                );
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
  }
  catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $result = array(
    'message' => 'There was an error sending the email',
    'sendstatus' => 1
    );
    echo json_encode($result);
    }
?>
```

The require file is in the same folder as contactForm.php.  No matter how many times I've tried to futz things around, every time I click the send message button, I get a 500 error from the Post request.  I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

Full disclosure, I'm relatively new to PHP, having come from the C# and JS world.  Haven't been able to figure out how to get errors posted to my console, which is another issue - the error is one I just can't find.  Tried multiple suggestions from these forums to get errors to post out (and solve the issue), with no luck.  Any thoughts, guys?

Edit: Found a log of the error on the Azure logs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error</h3> 
<h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>     <li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>   <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>     <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>  <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>    <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>  <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
<div id="details-left"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FastCgiModule</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PHP54_via_FastCGI</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr> 

</table> 
</div> 
<div id="details-right"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://abethel:80/assets/php/sendgrid-php/contactForm.php</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\assets\php\sendgrid-php\contactForm.php</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 

</table> 
<div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error. 
<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,9200">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
<p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p> 


</fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You can try and pin down the error from the website itself, though that's been fruitless for me, at abethel.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Turn on error reporting, log errors and potentially display error ini settings and check your logs. You could also put the files through a linter to make sure there are no syntax errors you've missed. Beyond that, debugging using something like xdebug for step-by-step, or sticking some dumps and exits in to see how far it gets.

Comment: Also, have you double checked the request and response headers to make sure the request is going through to where you expect with the values you expect?

Comment: From what I can tell, everything is set up alright with the headers.  As to the error reporting, how would I go about that through chrome?  I grabbed Chrome Logger, but haven't been able to get it to do anything useful yet.  Should also note that I'm using Visual Studio 2013, which has its own issues with php... :/  Azure has the PHP library server side, so.

Comment: Check your logs for a php error, 500 is a server level error.

Comment: Found this after messing around with getting the view set up, seems informative enough.  It's appended to the top post.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately solved the issue by adding the PHP Manager extension to track errors, altering ports, and adding the require line for the SendGrid\Email class.  Once the errors were visible, it all became so much simpler.

Ahhhh... php.  That love hate relationship.  Got it to work though, guys.  Thanks for the pointers in to the right direction.